# Redirect output files to directory in maven

Tags: java, maven

How can you redirect output files to a custom directory in maven? Lets say my output directory is test, and I want all my application output files to be written to test. How do I do this in maven?

Comment: You're not very clear what you mean and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If these "output files" are produced by your tests, simply define a prefix like `target/test` or something like that when creating these resources.

Alternatively, have a look at [this](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile), if this is what you need, but don't know how to explain.

Answer (score 0):

By "output directory", I assume you mean the "target" directory with all of your built artifacts and generated code.

```
<build>
    <directory>${buildDirectory}</directory>
</build>
```

Comment: No. Lets say in my application, I am reading files in an input folder, and processing them. If any error occurs while processing the files, I want to write the results to output directory. How do I achieve this in maven? I don't want the answer to my complete use case, but just need to know how do I redirect output to a specific directory in maven?

Comment: you mean copy the files in which you got error to another directory?

Comment: Maven won't be running anything in your application. Maven's job is to build your project, that's it. I'm not sure what you mean by "processing" files. If it's anything non-standard, you'll need a custom plugin for it.

Comment: Perhaps you mean you want to be able to configure at compile time the output path name via properties?

Comment: No. Like I said the only use case I want maven to take care of writing the output to an output directory. Its all configured in my code. When I run my application as a stand alone, it works, but when I use maven, it doesnt :( Clearly, I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include> **/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

### What about using: ***`Copy-maven-plugin`***

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.goldin</groupId>
    <artifactId>copy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-archive</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
                    <!-- Copy resources -->
                    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}/scripts</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>bat/setenv*.bat, bat/wrapper*.bat, bat/install*.bat, bat/uninstall*.bat</include>
                            <include>lib/core</include>
                            <include>*.jar</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}/scripts</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/conf</directory>
                        <include>resources, scripts</include>
                    </resource>
                    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
                    <!-- Copy directory -->
                    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}/spring</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/spring</directory>
                    </resource>
                    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
                    <!-- Copy "compile" dependencies -->
                    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}/lib</targetPath>
                        <dependency>
                            <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                        </dependency>
                    </resource>
                    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
                    <!-- Unpack two data archives -->
                    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}/data</targetPath>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>someData</groupId>
                                <artifactId>dependencyArchive</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>anotherData</groupId>
                                <artifactId>dependencyArchive</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <unpack>true</unpack>
                    </resource>
                    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
                    <!-- Create final archive and attach it as Maven artifact -->
                    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/zipName.zip</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
                        <pack>true</pack>
                        <attachArtifact>true</attachArtifact>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you redirecting the output in this?

Comment: @rickygrimes Here it is detailed which kind of files to copy and to where to copy